# Solaris 10 zlogin logs in, logs out immediately

Tags: solaris

On a SPARC v445 running Solaris 10 9/10, had to rebuild rpool and reattached the three existing mirrored zpools on the other existing disks, with their zfs filesystems and NG zones intact. The zones have been configured with `zonecfg -z ZONENAME create` etc.

... and are now online using `zoneadm -z ZONENAME attach -U` then simply booting after being in installed state, but I cannot zlogin to any of the zones except one. It shows that I am logged in, then a blank line, then immediately logged out again. When I try to login using `zlogin -C ZONENAME` I cannot; the error message is:

```
May 15 15:43:46 <hostname> login: open_module: stat(/usr/lib/security/pam_mkhomedir.so.1) failed: no such file or directory.
May 15 15:43:46 <hostname> login: load_modules: cannot open module /usr/lib/security/pam_mkhomedir.so.1
```

But `/usr/lib/pam_mkhomedir.so.1` does not exist, and it does not exist on my other servers, but those zones are accessible using `zlogin`.

I can only zlogin to the zones with `zlogin -S ZONENAME`.

What to do next? Thank you.

Comment: The error message states `/usr/lib/security/pam_mkhomedir.so.1` is missing but you later wrote `/usr/lib/pam_mkhomedir.so.1` does not exist. Double check you look for the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

There has AFAIK never been a `pam_mkhomedir` distributed with Solaris. It's possible someone installed one at some point. There is one [here](http://keutel.de/pam_mkhomedir/) for example. There must be an entry in `/etc/pam.conf` that mentions it. To get things working until you decide if you want to install it, you should be able to comment it out from the global zone to make logins work